# Is there an income inequality metric which also considers the total income?

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to compare some data I have about two companies, and in order to do so I need to compare their income inequality, but also to take in consideration the total income of each.

For example if we are to find that one company is slightly less equal, but has way higher total income, we would prefer her over the other. This is motivated by the fact that are we looking only at a subpart of the economy, hence the total income does matter.

I understand that most (if not all?) income inequality metrics don't evaluate that as a result of their definition which is purely a measure of inequality, but I didn't have any other name for what I am looking for.